# TypeDef as an overridable class feature

Tags: c++, typedef

If I have a class that contains a number of `typedef`'d variables, like so:

```
class X {

typedef token TokenType;

bool doStuff()
{
TokenType data;
fillData(&data);
return true;
}

};
```

Is there any way to override the `typedef` for `TokenType` in a derived class?

N.B. This is NOT a good place to use templates (This is already a templated class and any changes are likely to result in [EDIT: *infinite*] recursive definitions [`class X < class Y = class X < class Y . . .> >` etc.].)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is shadow, but not override. That is: you can define a derived class Y with its own typedefs for TokenType, but that will only come into play if somebody references Y::TokenType directly or via an object statically typed as Y. Any code that references X::TokenType statically will do so even for objects of type Y.

Answer (score 3):

Typedefs are resolved at compile time – making them overridable would be meaningless, since overriding is a feature of *runtime* polymorphism.

Simply redeclaring the typedef will work – though I'm not sure why you think templates would be a bad idea here – recursive templates are actually feasible.

Comment: Sorry, missed the word infinite from my recursive template sentence. This entire class is a work around for an infinitely recursive template problem, so adding this type as a template argument is impossible. Shame really, templates would be the best way to handle this.

Comment: Ok, infinite recursion might be kind of a problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you cannot override typedefs.

Long answer: A typedef is basically an alias or synonym for another type. They don't define new data types. They simply provide a way to give a type a new name.